# MediaStorage doesn't look like a module path. Django Error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS to host my media files from my django app. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/), and when I use the following code,

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'media'

MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/media/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'MediaStorage'
```

I get this error:

```
MediaStorage doesn't look like a module path
```

I have know idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: The tutorial says you should have `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'` instead of `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'MediaStorage'`.

Comment: @Alasdair I did this because I didn't want to create another .py file. Note that I have already tried this with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the full module path for DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE. See sample from documentation

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE

Default: 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
```

So put MediaStorage class in a storage.py module (path project/storage.py) and point DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE='project.storage.MediaStorage'

Comment: i've set DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage' and it works, thanks :)